# Extract video link added dynamically by JWPlayer

Tags: ajax, web-crawler, html5-video, jwplayer, advanced-rest-client

I would like to crawl a web page and extracts a video url embedded in the page. I first used `Inspect` tool and could easily see the embedded link as shown in the picture below:

[image: Inspect Chrome]

And the target `<video>` tag:

```
<video class="jw-video jw-reset" tabindex="-1" disableremoteplayback="" webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="" preload="metadata" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YYxKbKt3Apa8A2LkHKBJ7Fx6GU_iCIjEeGyyPJm_Ll-9hO4K8fDZV1pAbYprwpRhS5yFanf7=m18?title=[CayPhim.Net]-Bay-Vien-Ngoc-Rong-Sieu-Cap-tap-6.[360p]"></video>
```

I then tried to `View Page Source` tool and searched for the link but I couldn't find it. Instead, I found some `javascript` code that seems to be used to get and add the link to the page dynamically (at page loading time):

```
<div id="switchserver" style="height:100%;">
  <div id="phim_html5" style="height:100%;">
    <div class="loading"></div>
  </div>
  <script>$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://player.cayphim.net/jwplayer7/index_googima.php",
      type: "GET",
      cache: false,
      data: {
        "url": "8ce46ffa35805780571877c8ae5808f6a5e8898ebf9d294326735716694ccb4279505da51df9678cc8601a390a422d5e639449ec90332ee518e06f1dd579606d106f292d49bb38d9b2e80d0ee965a5c0e2911922e48ac972c521c4236512d356681404472b2cb39d9fff915bb4da21c8315d3fd6fc6cb0d2ed27183598661d40",
        "name": "QmF5IFZpZW4gTmdvYyBSb25nIFNpZXUgQ2FwIHRhcCA2",
        "sub": ""
      },
      success: function (msg) {
        $("#phim_html5").html(msg);
      }, error: function () {
        $("#phim_html5").html("<div class='player-error'>Server quá tải. Vui lòng chọn server khác bên dưới...</div>");
      },
    });
  });
  </script>
  <img style="display: none" src="http://image.cayphim.net/1553256337-lSC0nSX6Wj9dlOXfK29gK2iwoKF9D0p4YwnxYgmyCwmyBfJ29eW1wKpPetD3BkBKF9D0p4MsZPPjEReTD0UVY0K4YvoGKF9D0p42wODHaQKFo5pGMVmG9XmN05lP80DksxCQaHXKF9D0p4MMJwwhnyohFxsEYKF9D0p4wRJH5xYk1eXEr9mETjpng" />
</div>
```

Now I used `Advanced REST Client` to make a `GET` request to `http://player.cayphim.net/jwplayer7/index_googima.php` with parameters as specified in the `javascript` code but I got response containing some thing like this:

```
<div id="playerjw7">Trình duyệt của bạn không hỗ trợ xem phim bằng Player HTML5. Vui lòng cài đặt Chrome hoặc Firefox</div>
```

Yeah, it's Vietnamese, but it means "Your browser doesn't support Video Player HTML5. Please install Chrome or Firefox".

How could I programmatically scrape and extract the embedded video url?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.jw-video').src`

Comment: @zer00ne But I couldn't find down the tag in the downloaded web source.

Comment: JWPlayer dynamically creates the video tag so it doesn't actually exist unless the script `jwplayer.js` is loaded. I'm not familiar with scraping but if it involves extraction of web page content without a browser then that would explain why you can't find it.